# BigO, Running Time, Invariants - Learning Resources

Tags: algorithms, landau-notation, education, runtime-analysis

What are some good online resources that will help me better understand BigO notation, running time & invariants?

I'm looking for lectures, interactive examples if possible.

Comment: Have you considered reading a book?

Comment: related [question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/192/how-to-come-up-with-the-runtime-of-algorithms)

Comment: another related [question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57/how-does-one-know-which-notation-of-time-complexity-analysis-to-use)

Comment: Are there particular problems you face, or things you are interested in? Your question does not seem to be very focused.

Comment: As @Raphael notes, this would be answered more effectively if you could include a bit of information on where you're stuck - presumably you have *some* understanding of these concepts; can you briefly outline where you're finding difficulty?

Answer (score 7):

1. [MIT OCW Introduction to algorithms video lectures](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/)
2. [Design and analysis of algorithms stanford class](https://www.coursera.org/algo/auth/welcome)

Comment: [Here's one more, i got last day, it's quiet new, the course for "Theory of Computation" and "Algorithms" is up-coming.](http://www.udacity.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Since @Pratik's answer covers good resources for algorithms, I just wanted to mention that since you asked about big-O notation, Peter Braß has written a book on the topic, which you can find [here](http://www-cs.ccny.cuny.edu/~peter/obook.letter.ps).

*Update:* In response to the comments, I recommend this book for beginning students who are having trouble wrapping their head around big-O.  (Yes, every algorithms book ever covers it to some extent, but my experience is that one of the most common questions on math.SE is still basically "I am having trouble with big-O", so there must be a place for a more expansive treatment.)

Comment: Is it *a* book, or do you recommend it?

Comment: I recommend it for beginning CS students, and will mention it as a supplemental text the next time I teach algorithms.  Peter's data structures text is also quite nice.