# Reccurrence equation and finding suitable algorithm

Tags: algorithm-analysis, recurrence-relation

I'm given the following recurrence equation:

$$\begin{align*}
    T(1) &= 0\\
    T(n) &= T(n/2) + 1  && \text{when $n > 1$ is even}\\
    T(n) &= T((n+1)/2) + 1 && \text{when $n > 1$ is odd.}
\end{align*}$$

The problems I have are the following:

1) What does $T(1) = 0$ mean when it comes to writing computer program? It cannot be

```
return some_constant;
```

because this gives the complexity of $T(1) = 1$. Am I right?

2) I'm supposed to find an algorithm whose time complexity can be described using the given equation. I was thinking of Fast Power algorithm, because it has the same $O(n) = \log(n)$, but it's described differently:

$$\begin{align*}
    T(1) &= 1\\
    T(n) &= T(n/2) + 1 &&\text{when $n > 1$ is even}\\
    T(n) &= T((n-1)/2) + 1 &&\text{when $n > 1$ is odd.}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: It seems like they made a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) It doesn't mean anything, for two reasons:

- First of all, it's important to distinguish between an algorithm vs the running time of an algorithm.  $T(\cdot)$ is not an algorithm; it's a function.  For instance, $T(n)$ might be the running time of a computer program, as a function of the size of its input, but it's not the program itself.  Anyway, $T(n)$ is just a mathematical function: if it is intended to represent the running time of some algorithm, that should be stated explicitly.
- Second, every algorithm needs to take at least at least one step, so the running time always has to be at least one: it can never be zero.  Therefore, it doesn't make sense to have a running time of zero.  This might be a bit of a quibble/nitpick.

2) I suggest you do a bit more practice with the reverse: given a simple algorithm, work out a recurrence relation for its running time.  Once you feel like you're able to do that confidently, you'll probably find this exercise easy.

See also our reference question, [How to come up with the runtime of algorithms?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/192/755).  There's also a more advanced, sophisticated treatment at [Is there a system behind the magic of algorithm analysis?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/23593/755).