# Converting a algorithm to a runtime function

Tags: runtime-analysis, recursion

I need to find an upper limit for the runtime of $f(n)$.

```
f(n):
{
 g(n,1)
}

g(n,k):
{
 if n<=0 return;
 for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
 {
  print "I love data structures!";
  k++;
  g(n-1, k);
 }
 return;
}
```

I tried to think of it this way:

`for(i=1; i<=n; i++)` $\rightarrow (n+1)c_2$

`g(n-1, k)` $\rightarrow ng(n-1)$

$$f(n) = g(n,1) + c_f = c_1 + (n+1)c_2 + nc_3 + nc_4 + ng(n-1) + c_f$$

I am not sure about the recursion runtime analysis:

`g(n-1,k)` $\rightarrow ng(n-1)$

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! We get asked this kind of thing a lot, so we've written some reference material on the subject. Let me direct you towards our 
[reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599)
which cover your problem in detail.
Please work through the related questions listed there, especially http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/192/755 and http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/23593/755.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recursion for $g$'s running time is $$T(n)=n(T(n-1)+1)$$ where $1$ is the (constant) work done from the print statement and incrementing $k$. $g(n-1,k)$ and the constant work are called $n$ times from the for loop.
The recursion stops at $g(0,k)$ which has running time $T(0)=1$.

Solving this recursion on Mathematica (I suspect doing it by hand would involve induction or inspection) gave the result:
$$T(n)=\Gamma(n+1)+en\Gamma(n,1)$$
The complexity of this is
$$T(n)=O(\Gamma(n+1)+en\Gamma(n,1))$$
$$T(n)=O(n\Gamma(n,1))$$
Since $n$ is an integer, then we can reduce this to
$$T(n)=O(n!)$$