# Runtime analysis with recursion factor

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, recurrence-relation

I have this code:

```
if n is even
{
for i=1....n
   for j=1...i
      print j
return 8*foo(n/2)
}
```

Asking to calculate the running time $T (n)$. I thought at first that I can write the function like this:

$$T(n)= 8T(n / 2)+n^2$$
But according to the answers of the quiz, they are saying that the function looks like this:

$$T (n)= T(n / 2)+n^2$$
Why we can delete 8? Thank you very much!

Comment: You're not executing `foo` eight times but rather just multiplying the result of `foo` by eight.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis)?

Comment: Neither recurrence is accurate.

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57438/converting-a-algorithm-to-a-runtime-function#comment121503_57438

Comment: [Also posted on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37242187/781723).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1):

You're asked to calculate the *running time* of the segment, not the *value* returned. In terms of running time, multiplication by 8 is a single operation, so the running time is (roughly) $T(n)=T(n/2)+n^2$.