# Implement Immediate Smaller Element problem using Stack

Tags: time-complexity, arrays, stacks

**Immediate Smaller Element Problem:**

> Given an integer array `arr` of size $n$. For each element in the array, check whether the right adjacent element (on the next immediate position) of the array is smaller. If next element is smaller, update the current index to that element. If not, then update it to –1.

**Input:** `arr[] = {4, 2, 1, 5, 3}`

**Output:** `arr[] = {2, 1, -1, 3, -1}`

**Explanation:** Next to 4 is 2 which is smaller, so we
replace 4 with 2. Next of 2 is 1 which is smaller,
so we replace 2 with 1. Next of 1 is 5 which is
greater, so replace 1 with -1. Next of 5 is 3
which is smaller, so replace 5 with 3. The output for the last element is always going to be -1 because there is no element on right.

This is my solution:

```
void immediateSmaller(int arr[], int n) {
    int i = 0, j = i + 1;
    while(i < n - 1) {
        if(arr[i] > arr[j]) 
           arr[i] = arr[j];
        else 
           arr[i] = -1;
       i++;
       j++;
   }
   arr[j - 1] = -1;
}
```

My queries are:

- Is the time complexity of my solution $O(n)$ or $O(n^2)$? I think it should be $O(n)$ since there is only one loop here.
- How can this question be implemented using a `Stack` data structure? (My solution works fine but recommended approach is to use a `Stack`)

Comment: I don't really understand the original question. What is the input, and what is the desired output? Are there any examples provided?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I have edited my question (added input, output and explanation).

Comment: Can you tell us where you encountered this task?  Can you provide attribution or a link to the original source?  What is meant by "the current index"?  I find it hard to reconcile that with "For each element".  Please explain what is meant by "the current index".

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/192/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/23593/755

Comment: @D.W. This is the link to the question https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/immediate-smaller-element1142/1 ! The question is asking to update/replace the value at current index with the value at it's right adjacent index. (Condition- value at right adjacent index (at jth position) index is smaller than the value at the current index (ith position)).