# Time complexity of this for-loop

Tags: asymptotics, runtime-analysis, loops

I know, the inner loop here is `O(log n)`. But, I get confused by the multiplication in the outer loop part.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5*N; i++) {
  for (int j = 1; j <= 1000; j = 2*j) {
     doSomething(i, j);
   }
}
```

The correct answer to the question is, `O(N)` with regard to: *how many times does the function doSomething() run?* But, I want to know, how this is calculated.

`T(n) = O(log n)`, according to: https://www.quora.com/Can-anyone-tell-the-time-complexity-of-for-i-1-to-n-i-i*2-and-how

Comment: because $\log 1000 = O(1)$ and not $O(\log N)$.

Comment: `j=2*j` don't you see it?

Comment: $\log 1000$ is a constant. Even if it is `j=j+1` it is $O(1)$. It is a constant (i.e. fixed) number of iterations, regardless of the value of $N$.

Comment: It's NOT addition. It's doubling with multiplication. **j=2 * j**

Comment: I understand that its a constant. What about the outer loop, which actually goes: **i<=5*N**, that part is my concern, what time complexity is it? I am confused by the growth rate when multiplying.

Comment: So, even though, it's multiplying **5*N**, it too remains constant, hmm.

Comment: It is true that $O(5n)=O(n)$. Can you see why the outer loop works in $O(5n)$?

Comment: @nirshahar, I guess, because, it's constantly growing by **5x** ?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/23593/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/192/755