Palindrome Partitioning, help determining tight upper bound time complexity of my backtracking algorithm
Question (Leetcode 131; https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-partitioning/) Given a string s, partition s such that every substring of the partition is a palindrome. Return all possible palindrome partitioning of s.
The runtime to this problem is stated to be O(2^n * n), but this seems like an extremely loose upper bound if you use memoization to store all previously created substrings.
I don't know how to determine the tight upper bound time complexity for such a problem, using my implementation. My own guess is that since there are only n^2 possible substrings, each of max n length, you have n^3 work spread across the 2^(n-1) max possible leaf nodes. But I don't know what this looks like in Big-O notation, or if it's even right. How do people normally go about determining the upper bound time complexity for an implementation such as mine? I'm specifically curious about finding the time complexity of my specific approach to the problem, since it utilizes a backtracking approach which I've always had difficulty determining the tight upper bound for.
class Solution:
    def partition(self, s: str) -> List[List[str]]:
        # backtracking solution 
        @cache
        def isPalindrome(startIdx, endIdx):
            tmp1, tmp2 = startIdx, endIdx
            while startIdx < endIdx:
                if s[startIdx] != s[endIdx]:
                    return False
                startIdx += 1
                endIdx -= 1
            return s[tmp1: tmp2 + 1]

        def recursivelyDeterminePartitions(startIdx):
            if startIdx == n:
                res.append(currPartition.copy())
                return 
            
            for i in range(startIdx, n):
                if (substring := isPalindrome(startIdx, i)):
                    currPartition.append(substring)
                    recursivelyDeterminePartitions(i+1)
                    currPartition.pop()

        res = []
        currPartition = []
        n = len(s)
        recursivelyDeterminePartitions(0)
        return res


What is your question?  I don't see any question here.  We are a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a specific question about the task.  Also, if you can link to the original source, I encourage you to do so.

I'll edit it right away, but I'm basically asking for help determining the tight upper bound for this dynamic programming approach that I provide. The one that's given seems too loose to me.

I'm still not clear on what the question is.  I see only a single sentence that ends in a question mark: "this would be..right?"  Is that really what you want answered?  We discourage "please check my work, am I right?" questions, as they are unlikely to be useful to others.

My question is that, and sorry for not communicating it properly, is how to reconcile the total work done leading to the leaves with the number of leaves when determining time complexity. Usually, if you assume no overlapping paths to the leaf nodes, you can just say O(n*2^n), but in this case, if you believe there is n^3 work done across all 2^(n-1) leaf nodes, how do you determine the actual time complexity? Again, sorry if this is not what you were looking for.

Please don't put your question in the comments.  Instead, [edit] the question to clearly state the question you are asking.  We don't want people to have to read the comments to understand what you are asking.  We are looking to build a resource that will be helpful to others, so we need the question to be clearly stated (and hopefully something that will be relevant to others as well).  Is there a simple question you can ask?  Do you want to know the running time of your algorithm? The running time of the best algorithm?  I'm not sure what you mean by "reconcile".

I've edited my post, is this better @D.W.

It's not clear whether you want to know the running time of the particular algorithm found in this piece of code, or the running time of the best algorithm for the problem (also known as the complexity of the problem).

@D.W. thanks for your comments! I've made the post more specific

We're not a coding site, so questions about code are generally off-topic here. We'd prefer questions that don't require programming-language-specific knowledge.  Not everyone here knows Python -- especially the running-time of operations like @cache, append(), pop(), copy(), which are fundamental to answering this question.  So it's not clear to what extent this is a question about CS, vs a question about some particular code/language's standard library.

If you can translate your code to concise pseudocode understandable by everyone, that might be helpful, but I'm not sure that questions of the form "please tell me the running time of my code" are a great fit here, because it's not clear whether they will be useful to others in the future (will anyone else have that exact same question about the exact same algorithm?).

We have some general resources on how to analyze the running time of your code (e.g., https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/23593/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/192/755).
